# Java interface, which implementation is called

Tags: java, interface

I have to code a school project, to do that, they gave us some interfaces to help us to design the class implementations.

```
INode
```

is one of them :

```
public interface INode {

void buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs);
}
```

We have to implement this interface several times.

```
BlockNode
```

is one of them :

```
public class BlockNode implements INode {

@Override
public void buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs) {
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that in the main function they do that (the type of parse is INode):

```
root = parser.parse();
builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("PARSE TREE:\n");
root.buildString(builder, 0);
```

I don't get which implementation of

```
buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs)
```

is called.
It could be the one I wrote above (BlockNode) ? or any other I implemented ? I don't understand which one is called in first..

Comment: It depends on which implementation of `INode` is returned by `parse()`, of course. You can't tell by inspecting this code.

Comment: Without seeing the definition of the class of  `parser` to see what `parse()` returns we cannot tell you.  The whole point of using interfaces is that `parse()` returns an _appropriate_ implementation that provides the necessary functionality, and you don't actually need to know which one.

Comment: So if I return an implementation of BlockNode in parse(), the implementation that will be called in first is BlockNode ?

Comment: @JimGarrison I didn't implement entirely parse() because I didn't know which implementation I had to return yet. But EJP answers seems to be right ?

Comment: You haven't told us what `parse()` is doing, nor what the differences are between your concrete classes (i.e. `BlockNode` and the other ones).  You have to decide which implementation to return based on your requirements.

Comment: It's written in the doc that parse() does the following "Parses a program from file returning a parse tree (the root node of a parse tree)". The purpose of the program is to solve an evaluation, I've developped a tokenizer which returns every tokens of the evaluation, in parse() I'm supposed to build a tree from the token I got. I could show you an example of tree that parse() can build.

Comment: After reflection, I think that parse() should return a "parent node" which will contain the other nodes as child nodes.

Comment: So you're asking us what class's method will be invoked when you haven't even decided what that class should be? Your question is back to front.

Answer (score 1):

-
This will invoke method from **BlockNode**

```
INode root = parser.parse(); // Let's assume it return new BlockNode();
builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("PARSE TREE:\n");
root.buildString(builder, 0);
```

-
This will invoke method from **SomeNode**

```
INode root = parser.parse(); // Let's assume it return new SomeNode(); 
builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("PARSE TREE:\n");
root.buildString(builder, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a Parser Class.

```
public Parser {
    public INode parse(){
        return new BlockNode(); // this will return a new BlockNode.
    }
}
```

Now if you want to identify what type would it be to return to you without seeing the parse method. You can change your method in your INode 
from:

```
void buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs);
```

to:

```
String buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs);
```

and then when you implement it on your class nodes:

```
public class BlockNode implements INode {
     public String buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs) {
          return "BlockNode";
     }
}

or

public class OtherNode implements INode {
     public String buildString(StringBuilder builder, int tabs) {
          return "OtherNode";
     }
}
```

Now, in this way you can distinguish what type is return by printing it.

```
root = parser.parse();
builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("PARSE TREE:\n");
String nameOfClass = root.buildString(builder, 0);
System.out.println(nameOfClass); // this will identify what type is returned.
```